# Passing Terraform variables between Modules within Modules?

Tags: terraform, kubespray

I have an issue I have gotten stuck on building a module from the [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/tree/master/contrib/terraform/openstack) project.

I have the following folder structure:

```
terraform/
modules/
   kubespray/
      modules/
         compute/
         ips/
         network/
      main.tf
      variables.tf
roles/
    kubespray/
        terraform_setup/
             main.tf
```

Within the `kubespray/main.tf` module there are variables being passed around:

```
module "ips" {
  source = "./modules/ips"

  number_of_k8s_masters         = "${var.number_of_k8s_masters}"
  number_of_k8s_masters_no_etcd = "${var.number_of_k8s_masters_no_etcd}"
  number_of_k8s_nodes           = "${var.number_of_k8s_nodes}"
  floatingip_pool               = "${var.floatingip_pool}"
  number_of_bastions            = "${var.number_of_bastions}"
  external_net                  = "${var.external_net}"
  network_name                  = "${var.network_name}"
  router_id                     = "${module.network.router_id}"
}

module "compute" {
  source = "./modules/compute"
  ...
  k8s_master_fips                              = "${module.ips.k8s_master_fips}"
  k8s_master_no_etcd_fips                      = "${module.ips.k8s_master_no_etcd_fips}"
  k8s_node_fips                                = "${module.ips.k8s_node_fips}"
  bastion_fips                                 = "${module.ips.bastion_fips}"
  ...
}
output "private_subnet_id" {
  value = "${module.network.subnet_id}"
}

output "floating_network_id" {
  value = "${var.external_net}"
}

output "router_id" {
  value = "${module.network.router_id}"
}

output "k8s_master_fips" {
  value = "${concat(module.ips.k8s_master_fips, module.ips.k8s_master_no_etcd_fips)}"
}

output "k8s_node_fips" {
  value = "${module.ips.k8s_node_fips}"
}

output "bastion_fips" {
  value = "${module.ips.bastion_fips}"
}
```

If I run my terraform init/apply from inside the submodule in `modules/kubespray/` It works fine

If I run from my `role/kubespray` that has

```
module "kubespray" {
  source    = "../../../modules/kubespray"
  providers = {
    openstack.src = openstack
  }
}
```

it fails with

> Error: Invalid index
>
> on ../../../modules/kubespray/modules/compute/main.tf line 670, in
>   resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "k8s_node":  670:
>   floating_ip           = "${var.k8s_node_fips[count.index]}"
>       |----------------
>       | count.index is 0
>       | var.k8s_node_fips is empty list of dynamic

Help would be extremely appreicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `terraform`, the directory becomes an implicit "root module". As it's explained in the [Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) documentation, root modules can access TF inputs from the CLI or environment, but all other called modules need to have these passed in.

I'm assuming what's happening could be that your `~kubespray/variables.tf` input variables have default values assigned which are taking effect. If that's the case,  then these should be copied over to `~terraform_setup/variables.tf` and passed into the calling module:

```
module "kubespray" {
  source    = "../../../modules/kubespray"
  providers = {
    openstack.src = openstack
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this might have been my root cause, I reverted a lot of my changes and passed more from top level (root) module and things seemed to be happy. Thanks. QQ can I pass provider vars from this root module? output "output openstack_user_domain"?

Comment: @bison I might not have understood correctly. You could pass inputs to the child module for it to initialize a provider, if you don't want it to inherit one. Though, I don't think there's a way to reference providers, except for `{ provider = name|alias }` on resources, so I think you'll want to find one of it's suitable resources which provide outputs for the resolved provider configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Without asking for further information, my guess here is that you have an empty array being passed in (`${var.k8s_node_fips[count.index]}`) with a value greater than 0 for `var.node_root_volume_size_in_gb` and `var.number_of_k8s_nodes_no_floating_ip`, causing an error when trying to index an empty array for a string that the resource declaration requires.

```
Error: Invalid index

on ../../../modules/kubespray/modules/compute/main.tf line 670, in resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "k8s_node": 670: floating_ip = "${var.k8s_node_fips[count.index]}" |---------------- | count.index is 0 | var.k8s_node_fips is empty list of dynamic
```

According to the error, it seems this may be a interpolation error at `${var.k8s_node_fips[count.index]}`.
What it seems like is happening is that the variable is empty, but the `count` is set to a non-zero number, thereby causing `TF` to error out.

Looking at the original project code, seems like the `count` variable depends on `var.node_root_volume_size_in_gb` to be 0 to be set to 0; otherwise will set the count to the value of `var.number_of_k8s_nodes_no_floating_ip`.

Snippet that the error seems to be occuring at:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "k8s_node_no_floating_ip_custom_volume_size" {
  name              = "${var.cluster_name}-k8s-node-nf-${count.index+1}"
  count             = "${var.node_root_volume_size_in_gb > 0 ? var.number_of_k8s_nodes_no_floating_ip : 0}"
  availability_zone = "${element(var.az_list, count.index)}"
  image_name        = "${var.image}"
  flavor_id         = "${var.flavor_k8s_node}"
  key_pair          = "${openstack_compute_keypair_v2.k8s.name}"

  block_device {
    uuid                  = "${data.openstack_images_image_v2.vm_image.id}"
    source_type           = "image"
    volume_size           = "${var.node_root_volume_size_in_gb}"
    boot_index            = 0
    destination_type      = "volume"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at it, I understand what the error is telling me my real confusion is why it works fine when I run the terraform from the module itself. But when I run from something that calls the module, it fails. Seems `var.k8s_node_fips` isn't resolved if I don't run from the module directly